# massive INSERT - spring framework

Tags: java, sql, insert

I'm doing massive import in SQL Server using my Java application with Spring Framework and SimpleJdbcInsert class. The results are not good and I'm trying to optimize it.

I support every SimpleJdbcInsert does implicit transaction so I wish to make it explicit transaction with 'begin' at the start and 'commit' at the end of my file import procedure.

How can I do this? I'm looking, but can't find it. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

Thanks!

Comment: For you information, try not to use SimpleJdbcTemplate class since it will be deprecated in Spring 3.1.x (see https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6922)

Comment: SimpleJdbcTemplate? How come? Will that include SimpleJdbcInsert and SimpleJdbcCall? :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `SimpleJdbcInsert.executeBatch()` to execute multiple large sets of INSERTs. Maybe this could increase performance a bit.

Comment: But he wants to use transactions to ensure that data consistency and integrity are kept, so your answer solves only half of the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that hint, I'll take a look at it. It there a top limit? Because I do import of 1.000 - 500.000 records :(

Comment: I think there is no limit. The only limit you have is your heap! :-)

Comment: BTW: I was able to write about 950 rows/sec with SimpleJdbcInsert.execute()! It would be very interesting to know if this rate could be increased by using executeBatch()!